# Calculating the equation of a zig zag line on a graph

Tags: ios, math, graph, core-motion

I have plotted a time v/s some hardware sensor value graph. I have many readings and want to calculate a mean or any possible value (may be equation of a zig zag line, may be oscillatory motion or harmonic motion) to compare multiple readings.

I am recording data at the interval of 0.01 seconds.

Here is the graph plot of a single reading:
[image]

Here is the graph plot of multiple readings:
[image]

Also, equation of a curve can also be calculated. The data can be divided into time (2 second blocks), to calculate the equation of curve at that time.

Answer (score 0):

Add each value to a buffer when you plot it, then you can calculate whatever you want.

For the [mean](http://www.mathsisfun.com/mean.html) sum the buffer contents and then divide by the number of entries in the buffer.

To find equations for curves, [this page](http://cstl.syr.edu/fipse/graph/Unit8a.html) should help.

Comment: Any other method to do this? I think there is some better equation to calculate this rather than mean, which will return a more accurate value.

Comment: Do what? Mean is the only thing you specified in your question. "Any possible value" is a bit vague. Are you trying to derive the equation to predict future plots of the graph? Or past plots (in which case you can just look them up in a buffer)? Be more clear about what you are trying to achieve.